# When to substitute ‘z’ for ‘s’ in American English

Tags: american-english, orthography

Is there a rule as regards substituting the ‘s’ for a ‘z’ in American usage or does it apply to all words ending ‘ise’?

Comment: Would it be a surprise if you were advised that there's a whole lot of words that comprise a list of exceptions?

Comment: It's becoming increasingly common in BrE to use '-ize' in place of '-ise'. Not those in the previous comment, but words which have '-ise' added to a root, for example theory – theorise (theorize).

Comment: @WeatherVane Was *Americanise*  the first of these?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_spelling_differences#-ise,_-ize_(-isation,_-ization)) - you can check individual words in a good dictionary.

Comment: @DjinTonic when I enter **Americanise** into [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/) (from Oxford Dictionary) it comes up with **Americanize** (*also British* **Americanise**).

Comment: @WeatherVane I think they show all or most dual spellings that way.

Comment: You see the thing is I would ALWAYS want to use ‘ise’ but I am wondering if there are some instances where ‘ize’ is mandatory and the correct spelling. It becomes increasingly difficult when your spelling is second guessed by these spell checking algorithms.

Comment: I believe it only applies to verbs, but not all verbs; an exception that comes to mind is "comprise".